# How do I change playbackRate in html5 video contained in a you-tube iframe?

Tags: html, video, cross-domain

There is a chrome extension that allows playbackRate to be set and altered for html5 video contained in a you-tube iframe.

I would like to accomplish the same thing on Firefox (or, better, browser independently).

I am wondering if I have to do this through an add-on (to be able to do messaging cross site since my html is not on you-tube, but my video is), or if there is a simpler way (that might even work cross browser).

Any thoughts on the matter would be useful.

Per the excellent suggestion by Rachel Gallen (in the comments) here are some things I have tried:

```
$(function (){
  // a convenient way to get at things once the page renders
  $("button#stop-me").click(function() {
    var mytags = document.getElementsByTagName("video");
  });
});

$(function (){
  // a convenient way to get at things once the page renders
  $("button#stop-me").click(function() {
    var myframe = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe");
    for(p in myframe)
    {
      var mytags = myframe.document.getElementsByTagName("video");
    }
  });
});

$(function (){

  document.addEventListener('DOMNodeInserted', function(event) {
    var node = event.target || null;
    if (node && node.nodeName === 'VIDEO') {
      nodeList.push(node);
    }
  });

  $("button#stop-me").click(function() {
    alert(nodeList.length);
  });
});
```

The first one returns an empty "mytags".

The second one returns the list of iframes but errors on myframe.document call (as expected).

The third on never hits the nodeList.push(node) line and displays 0 for the count (as expected)

Answer (score 0):

If possible, it is best to use Youtube's API. You don't know what Youtube will display, it might be (for example) not even HTML5 video, it could be something else like flash. So while it might be possible to hack this, it's not the best method.

Comment: I do not see this offered in Youtube's API. Did I miss it?

Answer (score 0):

i haven't tested this but it should work

`document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0].playbackRate = 1.2`  should speed it up to 1.2 times the speed

(Likewise 0.7 will slow it down etc)

Comment: Tried it. It does not work (I think because the "video" tags are inside the iframe and the browser considers getting those a no-no because they are cross domain).